# ShopifyQL : shopify-cli Field 'appsNext' doesn't exist on type 'Organization'

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

```
╭─ error --------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                          
   The Partners GraphQL API responded unsuccessfully with the HTTP status 200 and errors:                                
                                                                                                                          
    \[                                                                                                                         {                                                                                                                     
      "message": "Field 'appsNext' doesn't exist on type 'Organization'",                                                 
      "locations": \[                                                                                                     
        {                                                                                                                 
          "line": 8,                                                                                                      
         "column": 9                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                 
      \],                                                                                                                  
      "path": \[                                                                                                           
        "query",                                                                                                          
        "organizations",                                                                           
                              "nodes",                                                                                                          

        "appsNext"                                                                                                       

      \],                                                                                                                  
      "extensions": {                                                                                                     
        "code": "undefinedField",                                                                                         
       "typeName": "Organization",                                                                                       
        "fieldName": "appsNext"                                                                                           
      }                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                     
  \]                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                         
   
 To investigate the issue, examine this stack trace:                                                                     
   at (graphql-request/src/index.ts:410)                                                                                 
      throw new ClientError(                                                                                              
   at step (graphql-request/dist/index.js:63)                                                                            
      op = body.call(thisArg, \_);                                                                                         
    at next (graphql-request/dist/index.js:44)                                                                            
      function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step(\[n, v\]); }; }                                                  
    at fulfilled (graphql-request/dist/index.js:35)                                                                       
     function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }                         
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj91L.png)

my shopify-cli version： 3.43.0

when i run the code： npm run dev
than this problem was display.

i try run npm run dev -- --reset  , it is also.